# Exception while trying to deserialize JSON into EntityFramework using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON which I'm getting from an external source into an Entity Framework entity class using the following code:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
IList<Feature> obj = serializer.Deserialize<IList<Feature>>(json);
```

The following exception is thrown:

> Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[JustTime.Task]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[JustTime.Task]'.

My model is simple: The Feature class has a one-to-many relation to the Tasks class. The problem appears to be the deserializer is trying to create a generic List to hold the collection of tasks instead of an EntityCollection.

I've tried implementing a JavaScriptConverted which would handle System.Collections.Generic.List but it didn't get called by the deserializer.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Also, what happens if you remove the assigment to `obj`?

Comment: I'm using .net v4. Removing the assignment doesn't help as the exception occurs inside the deserializer when deserializing a feature's list of tasks.

Comment: Please check the following links:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002940/json-and-circular-reference-exception
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588143/ef-4-1-code-first-json-circular-reference-serialization-error

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a list directly to an EF collection. You have to add to it. So deserialize to a POCO and then copy.

Comment: This is obviously the easy way out but would require me to duplicate the entire object model just to circumvent a minor technical issue, not really my preferred method of doing things.