# Circular reference detected exception while serializing object to JSON

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

Just as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588143/ef-4-1-code-first-json-circular-reference-serialization-error) post, I am getting a Json serialization error while serializing an Entity Framework Proxy:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.PurchaseOrder_446B939192F161CDBC740067F174F7A6059B0F9C0EEE68CD3EBBD63CF9AF5BD0'.

But the difference is, I **don't** have a circular reference in my entities, and it **only** occurs in our production environment. Locally everything works fine...

My Entities:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    Guid UniqueId { get; }
    int Id { get; }
} 

public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder : Entity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public string SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrderLine : Entity
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The GetCurrent action on my PurchaseOrderController throwing the exception:

```
public class PurchaseOrderController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public PurchaseOrderController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public JsonResult GetCurrent()
    {
        return Json(EnsurePurchaseOrder(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private PurchaseOrder EnsurePurchaseOrder()
    {
        var company = RouteData.GetRequiredString("company");
        var repository = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<PurchaseOrder>();

        var purchaseOrder = repository
                .Include(p => p.Lines)
                .FirstOrDefault
                (
                    p => p.Company == company && 
                         p.Username == User.Identity.Name
                );

        if (purchaseOrder == null)
        {
            purchaseOrder = repository.Create();
            purchaseOrder.UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
            purchaseOrder.Company = company;
            purchaseOrder.Username = User.Identity.Name;
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }

        return purchaseOrder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your company may have build issues.

Comment: @JayC: Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialization Issues with Web API and Entity Framework Contract First Many to Many Relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077328/serialization-issues-with-web-api-and-entity-framework-contract-first-many-to-ma), nothing to do with Circular references.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: I don't think this question is duplicate, as my entities do not contain circular references.

Comment: I should probably rename both question titles to `Circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.MyClass`.

Comment: Refer https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/36829

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your POCO entities are perfectly serializable. Your problem is that the dynamic proxies the EF runtime creates for you are usually not. You can set the `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` to `false` but then you lose lazy loading. My strong recommendation to you is to use `Json.NET` which supports serialization for EF entities:

[ADO.NET Entity Framework support accidently added to Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/07/10/ado-net-entity-framework-support-accidently-added-to-json-net.aspx)

[Popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

Comment: I'll have a look. Thank you. What I don't understand is why it "works on my machine"

Comment: Implemented the JsonNetResult as describe [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/06/17/31375.aspx) and it solved all my problems!

Comment: Mathijs, you posted the final solution to all my problems, thank you!

Comment: Seems like my original link doesn't work anymore. This one does:
http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net

Comment: i cant serialize the object without turn off the lazy load, is it possible to serizlize with json convert but not to turn off lazy load

Comment: JsonNetResult worked for me as well.  Linked changed: [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net)

Answer (score 45):

Option 1 (recommended)

[Try turning off Proxy object creation on your DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577852/209259).

```
DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Typically this scenario is because the application is using POCO objects (Either T4 Generated or Code-First).  The problem arises when Entity Framework wants to track changes in your object which is not built into POCO objects.  To resolve this, EF creates proxy objects which lack the attributes in the POCO objects, and aren't serializable.

The reasons why I recommend this approach; using a website means that you probably don't need change tracking (stateful) on Entity Framework objects, it free's up memory and cpu because change tracking is disabled and it will work consistantly on all your objects the same way.

Option 2

Use a serializer (like [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) which is already included in ASP.Net 4) that allows customization to serialize the object(s).

The reasons I do not recommend this approach is that eventually custom object serialization logic will be need to serial proxy objects as *other* objects types.  This means you have a dependency on logic to deliver a result downstream.  Changing the object means changing logic, and in an ASP.Net MVC project (any version) instead of only changing a View you have some thing else to change that is not readily known outside of whoever wrote the logic first.

Option 3 (Entity Framework 5.x +)

Use [.AsNoTracking()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking(v=vs.103).aspx) which will disable the proxy objects on the specific query.  If you need to use change tracking, this allows a nice intermediate solution to solution #1.

Comment: yay, 2 hours of searching for this little feature

Comment: when/where should this line be called? in the DbContext constructor?

Comment: It can be turned of in the constructor. If you are using EF5+, then I'd recommend using [AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) instead, and only when you want to serialize the result.

Comment: Option 1 should be the #1 answer.

Comment: AsNoTracking saved the day!

Comment: Setting: DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; works for me as I am only displaying data, not needing to track any changes.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Helped a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for option 3. Very helpful for serializing complex read only queries!

Answer (score 13):

I spent countless hours attempting all of the various solutions I found scattered throughout the web, including:

- [JsonIgnore]
- Internal Getters
- Disabling LazyLoadingEnabled and ProxyCreationEnabled
- Setting ReferenceLoopHandling to "ignore"
- Carefully using explicit loading where needed

All of which ultimately proved fruitless for me. Ignoring a property helped one query, but hurt 3 others. It felt like the programming equivalent to whack-a-mole.

The context of my problem was that the data going in an out of my application had to be JSON. No way around it. Inserts and updates obviously pose much less of a problem. But selecting data that's stored in a normalized database (and in my case including a version history) to be serialized is a nightmare.

The solution:

> Return the data (properties) you need as anonymous objects.

A code example:

> In this case I needed the 3 latest tickets, based on "Date Scheduled". But also needed several properties stored in related entities.

```
var tickets =
     context.TicketDetails
    .Where(t => t.DateScheduled >= DateTime.Now)
    .OrderBy(t => t.DateScheduled)
    .Take(3)
    .Include(t => t.Ticket)
    .Include(t => t.Ticket.Feature)
    .Include(t => t.Ticket.Feature.Property)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(
        t =>
        new {
            ID = t.Ticket.ID,
            Address = t.Ticket.Feature.Property.Address,
            Subject = t.Ticket.Subject,
            DateScheduled = String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", t.DateScheduled)
    }
);
```

And voila, no self referencing loops.

I realize this situation may not be adequate in all cases given that entities and objects may change. But it's certainly worth some consideration if all else fails.

Comment: As a side note to my response, a more robust solution, is Data Transfer Objects.

Comment: Nice and elegant solution ;)

Comment: Yes! `AsNoTracking` gave me another error. I was pretty sure the circular reference was due to a dodgy relationship (navigation?) that EF put into the autogenerated class, and I think without an explicit  select list it was trying to load thisnavigation. So my challenge *as usual* was finding the correct LINQ syntax to select a limited list. Thanks! Once I selected a limited list my error went away

Answer (score 2):

Whatever classes have the reference of other class just add attribute like this

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]
public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
```

Now everything work smooth

Comment: this worked for me with EF 7 where needed to add foreign key reference objects for child collections.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, what I have done is have passed only needed column to view , In my case. only 2.

```
 List<SubCategory> lstSubCategory = GetSubCateroy() // list from repo

 var subCategoryToReturn = lstSubCategory.Select(S => new { Id  = S.Id, Name = S.Name }); 

return this.Json(subCategoryToReturn , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, however I saw it both on production server and locally. Changing the DbContext configuration didn't quite solve my issue. A different solution was presented to me with the

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
```

attribute on DB entity references. See the post here if this sounds more pertinent to your issue.

[ASP.NET Web API Serialized JSON Error: "Self Referencing loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964407/asp-net-web-api-serialized-json-error-self-referencing-loop/23964620#23964620)

Comment: This seems not to work in my project, with attribute in metadata

Comment: Can you provide more detail?

Comment: I have added `[IgnoreDataMember]` to some properties but the circular reference exception remains

Answer (score 1):

In your `DbContext` class, add this line of code:

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

For example:

```
public partial class EmpDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public EmpDBEntities()
        : base("name=EmpDBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI for anyone reading, with this solution you lose lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

The circular reference happens because you use eager loading on the object.

You have 3 methods:

- Turn off eager loading when your loading your Query (linq or lambda)
     DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
- Detach the objects (= no eager loading functionality & no proxy)

  - Repository.Detach(entityObject)
  - DbContext.Entry(entityObject).EntityState = EntityState.Detached
- Clone the properties

  - You could use something like AutoMapper to clone the object, don't use the ICloneable interface, because it also clones the ProxyProperties in the object, so that won't work.
- In case you are building an API, try using a separte project with a different configuration (that doesn't return proxies)

PS. Proxies is the object that's created by EF when you load it from the Entity Framework. In short: It means that it holds the original values and updated values so they can be updated later. It handles other things to ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by un-checking Json.NET in the project Extensions in the Reference Manager.

(see the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqbXZ.png)

I also had to change the project.csproj file to map the correct path for the new version:

```
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.5\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

and still had to configure the web.config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Note that in the web.config file I was forced to refer to the OLDER (6.0.0.0) version though the installed version was 6.0.5.

Hope it helps!