# C# Entity Framework returning broken JSon when using Include in DbSet

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make a simple one-to-many relationship in C# using Entity Framework Core, the problem resembles a circular reference problem but no exception is being thrown.

My model classes are:

```
[Table("Restaurantes")]
public class Restaurante
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public List<Prato> Pratos { get; set; }
}

[Table("Pratos")]
public class Prato
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RestauranteForeignKey")]
    public Restaurante Restaurante { get; set; }

}
// One Prato (Dish) belongs to One Restaurant and one Restaurant can have many Dishes (Pratos)
```

I'm returning the Pratos from DB and I want that it returns also with their respective Restaurant:

```
context.Pratos.Include(r => r.Restaurante).ToList();
```

The context definition:

```
public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Restaurante> Restaurantes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Prato> Pratos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Prato>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Restaurante)
            .WithMany(r => r.Pratos)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

But on the browser, the JSON returned is something like:

```
[ {"id":1,"descricao":"prato 1","preco":1.50,"restaurante":{"id":1,"descricao":"fulano","pratos":[
```

It returns no more than that. I also tried the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) but didn't helped in terms of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like some code somewhere unconditionally swallowed a [circular reference exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16949520) while writing to a stream, resulting in incomplete JSON getting written to the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you probably need to change the `DefaultSettings` to handle the serialization

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
};
```

Or depending on your particular requirements

[`PreserveReferencesHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm)

> - **None** : Do not preserve references when serializing types.
> - **Objects** : Preserve references when serializing into a JSON object structure.
> - **Arrays** : Preserve references when serializing into a JSON array structure.
> - **All** : Preserve references when serializing.

[`ReferenceLoopHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ReferenceLoopHandling.htm)

> - **Error** : Throw a JsonSerializationException when a loop is encountered.
> - **Ignore** : Ignore loop references and do not serialize.
> - **Serialize** :Serialize loop references.

Comment: Thank you so match. Really, didn't know where to start. While again the solution is so simple, If you know it.