# Unable to return List from AJAX call MVC ? Following one example mentioned

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to return a list from `MVC controller`. Value is returned easily when I am returning a hard code value. But when I am returning a list, it gives me an error. Here is my code ,

Ajax call,

```
function MyFunction() {
    alert($('#DDlSurvey').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "ConductSurvey")",
        data: { prefix: $('#DDlSurvey').val() },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             // loadData(data);
            alert("Success");
           // alert(data)
        },
        error: function (data){
            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
        }
    });
    //$('#YourLabelId').val('ReplaceWithThisValue');
}
```

and my method is,

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(int prefix)
{

    List<SelectList> Questions = new List<SelectList>();
    List<Question> QuestionList = new List<Question>();
    List<string> ll = new List<string>();
    Question nn = new Question();
    SurveyAppEntities ObjectSur = new SurveyAppEntities();

    QuestionList = (from q in ObjectSur.Questions
                    join b in ObjectSur.SurveyQuestions on q.ID equals b.QuestionID
                    where b.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
                    select q).ToList();
   //return Json("OK");
  return new JsonResult  {Data=QuestionList, JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
}
```

When I return `OK` i get it but when i try to return QuestionList It is not returning data and display Failed

I am also using one link for help in which every thing is as it is link is,

http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/05/how-to-retrieve-database-data-show-using-jquery-mvc-asp.html

Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: Can you show us the error in the console when you execute the AJAX call?

Comment: I am not familiar with fiddler but shows some error that is "Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Question_BC320AE3E27C417948C0C84B1757D00A32BA9F8B496AD1AB2FBEB2D6D33E9DF7'"

Comment: That's problem with the reference in your db. Try adding AsNoTracking() before your ToList() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A circular reference was detected* indicates that EF generates proxy objects when generating query results which cannot be serialized using `JsonResult`. Assumed that `SurveyAppEntities` is your `DbContext` instance, then you need to do one of 2 options below:

**1) Disable proxy creation**

You need to set [`ProxyCreationEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.proxycreationenabled?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads) property to `false` which prevent EF creating proxy objects which cannot be serialized:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(int prefix)
{

    List<SelectList> Questions = new List<SelectList>();
    List<Question> QuestionList = new List<Question>();
    List<string> ll = new List<string>();
    Question nn = new Question();
    SurveyAppEntities ObjectSur = new SurveyAppEntities();

    // this line is mandatory
    ObjectSur.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    QuestionList = (from q in ObjectSur.Questions
                    join b in ObjectSur.SurveyQuestions on q.ID equals b.QuestionID
                    where b.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
                    select q).ToList();

    return Json(QuestionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**2) Disable query result tracking**

EF implements query result tracking with proxy objects which may be disabled by adding [`AsNoTracking()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking(v=vs.103).aspx) to each table entities:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(int prefix)
{

    List<SelectList> Questions = new List<SelectList>();
    List<Question> QuestionList = new List<Question>();
    List<string> ll = new List<string>();
    Question nn = new Question();
    SurveyAppEntities ObjectSur = new SurveyAppEntities();

    QuestionList = (from q in ObjectSur.Questions
                    join b in ObjectSur.SurveyQuestions on q.ID equals b.QuestionID
                    where b.SurveyID.Equals(prefix)
                    select q).AsNoTracking().ToList(); // prevents result tracking

    return Json(QuestionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Note:**

You may also try to return only required properties instead of entire `ObjectSur.Questions` object.

Related issue:

[Circular reference detected exception while serializing object to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949520/circular-reference-detected-exception-while-serializing-object-to-json)

Comment: got sicken tired of this issue your solution rocks !

Answer (score 0):

Simply return list like below

```
return Json(QuestionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Change JsonResult to ActionResult in Method Declaration

Comment: Brother i tried but it is returning simple string in current case than why not List :(

Comment: You have to parse JSON at jquery end.. It will always return you a string.

Comment: var json = $.parseJSON(data);

Comment: means use in Success function ?