# Convert IEnumerable model to Json array

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I'm trying to convert an IEnumerable model to Json array in my view via jQuery as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<SamsungTools.Models.SaleCenter>

var arr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

But an error raised as:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SaleCenter_7A0CE6A0DDE13787CC1DADED551C4B390761E2E4BC6E0E6F5B8DF894725F4934'.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: The issue isn’t with your code but with your data which contains a circular reference, e.g. in your model hierarchy one item A references item B, item B references item A again or an item C which references item A.

Comment: Check if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23490311/2348125

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Circular reference detected exception while serializing object to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16949520/3744182).

Comment: Thanks @ckuri, it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ckuri, Solved by creating a new view model with specified properties and pass a list of it to view. In new view model I removed two properties which were caused self referencing circular loop in JSon convert.

Finally,
Model:

```
public class SaleCenterViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleEN { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    public string Lng { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AddressEN { get; set; }
    public static SaleCenterViewModel Set(SaleCenter saleCenter)
    {
        return new SaleCenterViewModel
        {
            Title = saleCenter.Title,
            TitleEN = saleCenter.TitleEN,
            Code = saleCenter.Code,
            Lat = saleCenter.Lat,
            Lng = saleCenter.Lng,
            Phone = saleCenter.Phone,
            Address = saleCenter.Address,
            AddressEN = saleCenter.AddressEN
        };
    }
}
```

Store:

```
public List<SaleCenterViewModel> GetAllSaleCenters()
{
    return
        db.SaleCenters
        .Select(SaleCenterViewModel.Set)
        .ToList();
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Map()
{
    GeneralStore gs = new GeneralStore();
    ViewData["Cities"] = gs.GetCitiesHaveSaleCenter();
    ViewData["Areas"] = gs.GetAllAreas();
    var saleCenters = gs.GetAllSaleCenters();
    return View(saleCenters);
}
```

View:

```
@model List<SamsungTools.ViewModels.SaleCenterViewModel>

<script>
    var arr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
</script>
```