# Code management: How to manage dynamically generated javascript?

Tags: design-patterns, version-control, templating

I've just started at a company who have a code-base where most js/css is mixed in with the views, I'm going through the process of dividing it out into separate files.

But I keep coming across a situation where server variables are being inserted into the client-side code, which stops me being able to just cut and paste.

It's often data that is required on pageload, so making a request is not an acceptable solution.

We're using c# asp.net, but I've come across the problem in PHP too.

Is there a code management best practice for dealing with this? I'm eager to bring the idea of "separation of concerns" to the mess here, but I can't decide where this code should live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid just leaving this as tumbleweed - I'll answer this myself.

We've decided that we'll just serialize in the template rather than iterating through arrays as people have previously done.

It seems to me now that the problem is caused by developers being lazy, not any technical challenge.

See [Outputting Json with the Razor view engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367062/outputting-json-with-the-razor-view-engine)