# How to select all properties except for a specific property?

Tags: c#, linq

In a Linq query, if I'd want to select all properties except for a specific property, what would I do?

I *can't* use `Select()` and specify all properties except the one I don't want, because I don't know some of the properties (I query a list of abstract class).

I can't also just select all properties because that'd throw a circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type X. (I'm serializing the object to Json)

Is there any `Filter()` method or some extension method I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `Select(ALL_STUFF).Except(WHAT_YOU_DONT_WANT)`?

Comment: I think the short answer is no; the long answer is, you'll have to be more specific in what you intend to do for a workaround.

Comment: @Cipi: `Except` is about rejecting whole elements of the result, not about projecting elements.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: Some people seem to just down-vote things they dislike rather than sticking to the site guidelines - questions that show little research or are badly expressed, answers which show bad-practise or are just plain wrong. I'll upvote it to help :)

Comment: Projection wise, the opposite of Select is Select-something-else. Can you give an example of what you have coming in and what you would like to see coming out?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, you can't do that - there's nothing like that at all. Bear in mind that you have to end up with a particular type as a result of the projection... if you don't know what properties you're going to select, how can you have such a type?

If you're querying a list of some abstract class, is there any reason you don't want to just keep a reference to the instance of that abstract class? What benefit is there in separating it out into specific properties? Or are you *really* trying to avoid seeing those properties later on, e.g. for databinding?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to avoid some properties, not for databinding, but because some properties create a circular reference. I have edited my question to explain this, so maybe we can find another solution?

Comment: @Alon: It sounds like you need to change how you serialize rather than the query then.

Comment: Umm, how would I do that? I'm using ASP.NET MVC's `Json()` method to return a `JsonResult` in my view.

Comment: @Alon: You'd have to see whether there's anything within that call that can do so - but do you see why you *can't* do it at the LINQ level? What type would you expect the result to be, when the properties aren't known until execution time? You could *potentially* do something around this using dynamic typing, but it would be unusual to say the least.

Comment: When I see this I was like whaaaaatttt!!!! This is wrong however it was written 2011 asuming it was right for that time however It is kinda possible...

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: I answered the question that was asked - and the answer is still right for that. I don't regard "modifying existing objects" as "selecting other properties".

Comment: @JonSkeet you are a hero to me when it comes to C#, and you are right "modifying existing objects" is not "selecting other properties". It is merely a situational solution that was thought outside the box. Your answer is still acceptable. My apologies... and if my vote wasnt locked I would change but it seems it requires an edit to be able to do that..

Answer (score 3):

If JSON serialisation is the *real* problem you are trying to fix then check out the post called [JSON and Circular Reference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002940/json-and-circular-reference-exception). One recommendation is to use the [ScriptIgnoreAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) which "Specifies that JavaScriptSerializer will not serialize the public property or public field". There are also some other clever ways around it in the post worth considering.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I was looking for, but since the real answer for the question "what is the opposite of .Select" is Jon Skeet's answer, I will have accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many properties you're talking about, your best bet could be just to type out the ones you DO want. As Jon Skeet notes, there's nothing pre-built in LINQ that does what you're describing, because it's a very unusual task.

That being said, if you're dealing with so many properties that it's a huge pain to write -- e.g. something like...

```
return query.Select(q => new
                   {
                       Prop1 = q.Prop1,
                       Prop2 = q.Prop2,
                       //...
                       Prop3000 = q.Prop3000
                   });
```

...then there are two options that spring to mind:

- Use a script to generate the code for you - probably by using reflection to print a list of the class's properties and C&Ping it into your code.
- Use reflection in your live code, using the [PropertyInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) and filtering by `PropertyInfo.Name`.

I've done both of these (for other reasons), so I know they work. However, I strongly recommend the first option if you can get it running. Using reflection in the live code will be slower, probably more error-prone, and more difficult to understand when another developer comes along. The only reason I used it was because the class I was working with came from somewhere else, and was subject to frequent changes.

If you do use the first one, might want to keep the code in a separate helper class. Nobody wants a jillion lines of property-selection cluttering up an important method.

Comment: Thank you, I have to end up with the first option, sadly the entity contains 150 properties and I only need 149, ohmygod!

Answer (score 1):

Well, what exactly is it you want to achieve? If you want to solve circular issues before serialization, why not traverse the object model then, and set all backreferences to null?

```
public class MyClass{  
  public List<MyClass> Children {get;set;}  
  public MyClass Parent {get;set;}  

  public void ClearParents(){  
    this.Parent = null;  
    this.Children.ForEach(e => e.ClearParents());  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just because you mentioned

> (I'm serializing the object to Json)

first we define a model with json `NullValueHandling` for example;

```
[JsonProperty("intProp", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int? IntProp { get; set; } // it can be any prop with nullable

[JsonProperty("stringProp", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string? StringProp { get; set; } // I said, it can be any prop with nullable

[JsonProperty("objectProp", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public SomeObject? ObjectProp { get; set; } // ...any prop with nu... nwm u got the idea...
```

then we get the referenced values and just remove the one we dont need via nullifying;

```
var test = test.Select(x => { x.ObjectProp = null; return x; }).ToList();
// see the trick here? re-object the object with a prop nullified..
```

then if you serialize with json the ending result will be all fields except the one we dont need..

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

this method can be achieved via;

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: This modifies everything in the collection. That's very much *not* the same as "selecting all except some properties", and it's also very much against the spirit of LINQ. (Mutating existing objects within a LINQ query is a bad idea in general IMO.)

Comment: @JonSkeet generally speaking yes you are right. however mutation is usable in this senario. I just merely given a solution to a spesific senario here it is not about the best practices.. yet I would like to encourage you to give me an example with best practices to solve such an issue..

Comment: "however mutation is usable in this senario" - how can you *possibly* know that? Do you have intimate knowledge of the OP's situation, including whether they actually expect to be able to use the existing objects for other operations? (They never said they were *only* serializing the objects to JSON, then discarding them.) Your approach is fundamentally destructive *and* this doesn't answer the question (despite your claim in a comment on my answer that what's being asked *is* "kinda possible", when it's not).

Comment: Still `Select`s all properties. Then it serializes the result. That step is not LINQ-related and also makes the result not suitable for further composing on the LINQ query. Also, note that many properties won't be nullable. All in all not a solution that's generally applicable.

Comment: Yep you all are right as mentioned before not generally applicable but solves the problem. It is not a good way to do it but it does the job. I dont get why people are getting so fierce about this right now but it actually does solves what is OP written as a problem. It is not about you guys not liking how it is being done, it is about solution it self... Please be open minded for a sec...

Comment: @GertArnold preciated and given the first thumbs up.. may be I should speak more singular.

Comment: Again: we don't know that it *would* have solved the problem the OP faced, because it makes an assumption that the OP is happy for their existing objects to be mutated. (And that assumption isn't even stated in the answer.) It's *possible* that it would solve the problem, but you can't state with certainty that it's an applicable solution for the OP.

Comment: (IMO a better solution would be a custom JSON converter - if the problem is making a decision about *serializing* or omitting specific properties, I'd focus on that of the domain of the solution as well.)

Comment: @JonSkeet probably yes a custom converter can filter with more mobility. I just had a similar issue back in time got me couple of hours to accidentally find out that I can re-purpose objects in LINQ with this method. I did too had to cancel out some props from a class and receive the rest and were resulting in JSON to send it to another service so it was fitting the situation. I thought OP might had a similar issue.