# Cant get ASP.NET MVC 6 Controller to return JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have an MVC 6 project in which i am using Fiddler to test out Web API. If i take the following controller action which uses EntityFramework 7 to return a List. Then the html will render fine.

```
[HttpGet("/")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = orderRepository.GetAll();

    return View(model);
}
```

But when i try to return a Json response instead i get a 502 error.

```
[HttpGet("/")]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var model = orderRepository.GetAll();

    return Json(model);
}
```

Any Idea on why the object isnt serialized into json correctly?

Comment: Can you add some network data of the request and response from Fiddler?

Comment: Since you get a 502, there’s an error on the server side. So debug the project and look at the logs.

Comment: It says 502 Bad Gateway HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway 
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?WjpcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFZpc3VhbCBTdHVkaW8gMjAxNVxQcm9qZWN0c1xKZW5Tb2xvXHNyY1xKZW5Tb2xvXHd3d3Jvb3Q=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 16 Jan 2016 23:16:58 GMT
Content-Length: 4939 @poke

Comment: You can just use `public IEnumerable<Order>` or `public IEnumerable<object>` instead of `public JsonResult` and return model. I think that [the link](https://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfromwebapi2.html) will answer all your questions.

Comment: @Oleg I have tried IEnumberable and still no luck. I did notice that in fiddler the content types Says text/html. Could this be the reason. Shouldnt ObjectResult change the content type to json?

Comment: @Oleg I have narrowed the problem down even further. It seems that the .Include(o => = o.User) statement in my repository is making trouble for the serialization to json. If I take that out it seems to work fine. But with it in it doesn't work. Any idea how to correct the problem?

Comment: Can you check what is your JSON output on the server side which is being sent across to client?

Comment: @AnkitVijay If i set a break point on the return in the action i can inspect the model. It has everything that the Entity should have. They only thing i can notices is they may be a circular reference going on. It gets the order and that order has a user and that users has a List of order which have the user. It seem like that may be causing confusion. Is there a way to stop it from the recursion it is doing?

Comment: Circular reference always has been issue with JSON. Try out this link for circular reference to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002940/json-and-circular-reference-exception

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all you can use `IEnumerable<Order>` or `IEnumerable<object>` as return type instead of `JsonResult` and return just `orderRepository.GetAll()`. I recommend you to read [the article](https://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfromwebapi2.html) fr additional information.

About another error with Bad Gateway. Try to add `Newtonsoft.Json` in the latest version 8.0.2 to dependencies in `package.json` and to use use

```js
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

By the way one can reproduce the error "HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway", which you describes if I just set breakpoint on the return statement of working code and wait long enough. Thus you will see the error "HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway" very soon on many common errors.

You can consider to us more helpful serialization options. For example

```js
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        // handle loops correctly
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

        // use standard name conversion of properties
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        // include $id property in the output
        options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
            PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you that works. Are there options for xml as well?

Comment: @Dblock247: MVC don't returns typically XML data. The settings are specific settings of  `Newtonsoft.Json` , which is default JSON serializer in ASP.NET 5.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can you recommend an XML Serializer?

Comment: @Dblock247: First of all you should add `"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml"`. Then you have the formatters which you can use to configure Mvc for usage of Xml as input or output format. You can try to implement yourself and to ask *new question* if you would have problems.

Comment: @Dblock247: I see that you never used voting before. It's really important right, which allows gives tips for searching that the content is helpful. It helps other visitors to find the answer/question. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) for example. You have right to vote about 30 answers **per day**. You should active use the right if you want help other.

Comment: Didn´t work for 5.0 .Net Api