# Controller.json set Serialization.ReferenceLoopHandling

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

is there a way to set Controller.Json ReferenceLoopHandling property?

It is currently causing a self referencing loop when parsing entities with navigation properties defined on both ends. This problem is solved by setting

```
ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Is there a way to do this for Controller.Json method?

I found this piece of code, but it does not seem to work.

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(option =>
        {
            option.OutputFormatters.Clear();
            var jsonOutputFormatter = new JsonOutputFormatter();
            jsonOutputFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

            option.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, jsonOutputFormatter);
        });
```

Comment: Try to follow [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34836837/315935).

Answer (score 15):

I think that a prettier solution for this is to add JsonOptions in your ConfigureServices like:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
                               Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is from some time ago but it still can help other people.

Try this in your ConfigureServices method of the Startup class:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    ((JsonOutputFormatter)options.OutputFormatters.Single(f => f.GetType() == typeof(JsonOutputFormatter))).SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

or

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var jsonOutputFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.SingleOrDefault(f => f.GetType() == typeof(JsonOutputFormatter)) as JsonOutputFormatter;
    if (jsonOutputFormatter != null)
        jsonOutputFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Comment: Alternative form for core:  `services.AddMvcCore()    .AddJsonFormatters(j => j.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with .NET Core 3.0.

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(
    options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =
        Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Comment: I had to add a NuGet reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`