# Getting weird json result back

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

This is my .net core 2 web api method,

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<Clients> GetClientsWithUsers() // public IEnumerable<Clients> GetClientsWithUsers()
    {
        var clientsWithUsers = _context.Clients.Include(c => c.Users).ToList(); //.ToArray()
        return clientsWithUsers;
    }

    public partial class Clients
    {
        public Clients()
        {
            Users = new HashSet<Users>();
        }

        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? MaxUsers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Users> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastAccessed { get; set; }
        public Clients Client { get; set; }
    }
```

and the result I am getting in the browser is truncated:

> [{"clientId":1,"name":"TestClientName","maxUsers":12,"Users":[{"id":3,"name":"some
>   name","clientId":1,"lastAccessed":"2015-11-27T00:00:00"

I am not sure why I am getting broken structure.

Comment: What structure is broken? It looks fine to me. Write your expected output too.

Comment: @Adriani6 - it has been truncated.  Upload to https://jsonlint.com/ to see the problem.

Comment: @dbc Ah. Of course. Didn't see the ending of the string. I blame the phone... ignore my first comment.

Comment: Could your framework have swallowed a [self referencing loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7397207/3744182) error trying to serialize `Clients.Users[0].Client`?  If that happened the JSON might have been only partially written; indeed it appears to have been cut off right before serializing `Users[0].Client`.  Try marking `public Clients Client` in `User` with `[JsonIgnore]`, `[IgnoreDataMember]` or `[ScriptIgnore]` as appropriate to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @dbc you are right, I was just trying to convert it into JSON on web api side and get this error, 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'Client' with type...

Comment: believe this should fix the issue, going to try it, thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892509/controller-json-set-serialization-referenceloophandling

Comment: Nope, it's not fixing the issue for me, there seem to be a issue on git but no solution, https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2285

Comment: What if you just add `[IgnoreDataMember]` and/or `[JsonIgnore]` to `Users.Client`?  Do you want to serialize it, or skip it?

Comment: for some queries I will need it too, but I guess if I am not removing it completely there still be some way...