# return collection in asp.net core api

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a small api with these models with ef-core

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a controller get function:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Home()
{
    // retrieve the user info
    //HttpContext.User
    var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");
    var user = await _appDbContext.Users.SingleAsync(c => c.Id == userId.Value);            

    return new OkObjectResult(new
    {
        Message = "This is secure API and user data!",
        user.FirstName,
        user.LastName,
        user.Accounts
    });
}
```

How do I get the controller to return the list of accounts? In debug I can see the "accounts" variable with the correct data, I'm just not sure on how to format that var and return it in the api

I am currently recievng:

```
{
"message": "This is secure API and user data!",
"firstName": "Bill",
"lastName": "Johnson",
"serviceAccounts": null
}
```

UPDATE: So I ran the app using the dotnet command line and got

```
{"firstName":"Bill","lastName":"Johnson","serviceAccounts":[{"id":1,"camsUser":{"firstName":"Bill","lastName":"Johnson","company":null
```

Comment: What response are you currently receiving?

Comment: Are you using Ef-Core?

Comment: Question, if you are simply setting the value which is a derived object, why do you define user properties?  You can simply pass `user` to value as an object to be returned?  Which the consumer could go through each property.

Comment: use Include for the Accounts.

Comment: Does the `user` object retrieves contains accounts? If not then you should Include it as part of fetch statement

Comment: so I did a include like the one below with the accounts and Visual Studio is showing a 200 response, but postman is throwing errors

Comment: @user3600224 what kind of errors?

Comment: @Valuator 
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:55613/api/dashboard/home.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General

Comment: You aren't seeing a `JsonSerializationException` when debugging when you return your object by chance, are you?

Comment: nope. I wrapped everything in a try catch JsonSerializationException block and it still ran fine

Comment: postman is showing Error: read ECONNRESET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with this:

```
var userId = _caller.Claims.Single(c => c.Type == "id");
var user = await _appDbContext.Users.Include(s =>s.Accounts).SingleAsync(c => c.Id == userId.Value);
var accounts = user.Accounts.Select(a => new
        {
            a.AccountNumber,
            a.id
        });
return new OkObjectResult(new
        {
            user.FirstName,
            user.LastName,
            accounts
        });
```

Comment: I'm guessing it was a circular reference error when serializing the Json.

Comment: yep, that was it.

Comment: You might try adding `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` to your `Startup.cs` file as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39642105/7897176 to avoid having to instantiate a separate collection like that, results may vary though.

Answer (score 0):

Iif the child entities are setup for lazy loading then you should fetch the accounts and user as

```
var user = await _appDbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Accounts).SingleAsync(c => c.Id == userId.Value);
```

Comment: This isn’t necessary anymore.

Comment: @Nikolaus indeed, in fact Visual Studio will nag you to simplify it now.

Comment: The "Also, if the child entities..." portion of this answer is the solution to the OP's issue. Its kind buried in the unrelated stuff about the return type.

Comment: I did this and visual studio is shows a 200 success response, the user var has the account information, but postman throws errors

Comment: @Valuator /Nikolaus - Thanks, I's not aware of that if anonymous type is declared without prop name. I've updated my answer to have relevant part only. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3600224 - Check https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3503 & https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2217 and see if this resolves your problem.