# jqGrid setting multiselect checkbox id and name to a different value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, free-jqgrid

I've just added free jqGrid to my ASP.NET MVC web application. Whist it is working great for the most part, I would like to set the values for "id" and "name" attributes on the multiselect checkboxes to an Id column value from a different column in the table?

Instead the checkboxes are set as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="jqg_list2_jqg30" class="cbox" name="jqg_list2_jqg30" aria-checked="false">
```

How do I replace the jqg_list2_jqg30?

I've been following this demo where the id and name attributes on the checkboxes are set correctly, but I can't see what I am doing differently - http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

This is the logic for jqGrid

```
$("#list2").jqGrid({
        url: 'https://localhost:44319/Package/GetPackages/2',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Description'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 55, sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 90, searchoptions: { "sopt": ["bw", "eq"] } },
            { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 90 }                
        ],
        rowNum: 25,
        rowList: [25, 50],
        pager: '#pager2',
        toppager: true,
        sortname: 'Id',
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "auto",
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiPageSelection: true,
        multiselect: true,
        selarrrow: [],
        caption: "JSON Example",
        loadonce: true,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }
    });
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2',
        { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, view: false, refresh: true });
    jQuery("#m1").click(function () {
        var s;
        s = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
        alert(s);
    });
```

I know I could write some custom logic to do this but I don't think this is required as the example above shows and is something that should work out of the box?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly you need here ?

Comment: Hi, I want to set the id and name attributes on the checkboxes created by multiselect to Id value from the Id column. Thanks

Comment: The option `contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8"` will be ignored in your current code because `contentType` is unknown options of jqGrid. If you need to specify the option of `jQuery.ajax`, which uses jqGrid internally, then you should uses the option `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8" }` instead. Please include additionally always the version of jqGrid of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which you use and to add [free-jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info) tag to the question if you really use "free jqGrid" fork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some common misunderstandings which follow your question. I suppose that you get the ids of selected elements by using `jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')` and then you need to get *detailed information* about the selected items: "id" and "name".

The first problem is the rowid of your grid. You don't included any test data returned from `url: 'https://localhost:44319/Package/GetPackages/2'`, but I can guess that it's array of items like `{"Id": 123, "Name": "Some name", "Description": "Some description"}`, where the value of `Id` come from the database and all the values are **unique**. The internal organization of jqGrid *require* that every row of the grid (every `<tr>` element of the HTML table with the main data) has `id` attribute with an unique value. One names the value of `id` attribute as "rowid". By default jqGrid examines the input data for `id` property and uses the values as rowid. If you use `Id` instead of `id` then you can add `jsonReader: { id: "Id" }` to fix the problem and to inform jqGrid to use it as the input of the rowids. Alternatively you can configure `Newtonsoft.Json` settings of your ASP.NET MVC application to assign `ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();`. The exact place of the assignment in the code depends on the version of ASP.NET MVC, which you use. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836837/315935) shows where you can assign the configuration settings in ASP.NET Core. I personally use such settings because I try to follow the standard name conversions of C# and JavaScript.

One more option which you have is adding `key: true` to the column `Id`. It will do almost the same as `jsonReader: { id: "Id" }`.

If you have the rowid (or the array of rowids by `jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')`) then you can easy get the value from any column or the value of any properties of the corresponding data item. If you use `loadonce: true` then the items of the data returned from the server will be saved *locally* in `data` parameter, like in the case of usage `datatype: "local"`. You can easy get the data item using `getLocalRow` method. You can change the code

```
jQuery("#m1").click(function () {
    var s;
    s = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
    alert(s);
});
```

to

```
jQuery("#m1").click(function () {
    var $grid = jQuery("#list2"), i, item,
        ids = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");

    for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        item = $grid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", ids[i]);
        alert("rowid=" + ids[i] +
            "\nId=" + item.Id +
            "\nName=" + item.Name +
            "\nDescription=" + item.Description);
    }
});
```

By the way, I recommend you to remove unneeded `index` properties from all columns (from `colModel`) and remove some options of jqGrid with default values (`mtype: 'GET'`, `height: "auto"`, `sortorder: "asc"`, `selarrrow: []`). I recommend you to remove empty div `<div id="pager2"></div>` from your HTML page and to use `pager: true` instead of `pager: '#pager2'`. Free jqGrid will generate the div for the page in the same way like for the toppager (see `toppager: true`). It simplifies the code. You can get the id selector of generated pager (if you need) using `jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'pager')`, but one don't need it in the most cases. Instead of using

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2', {...});
```

you can use just

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', {...});
```

which will add navigator buttons to *all pages* of the grid.

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I was looking for. Setting `key: true` on the Id colModel gave me the desired behaviour. I've done as you suggested and tidied up the properties. Thank you so much.

Comment: @jgill09: You are welcome! The option `jsonReader: { id: "Id" }` could be used in combination with `key: true`. You will see the advantage if you would add editing in the grid. By editing jqGrid will send `id` property by default, but after `jsonReader: { id: "Id" }` it will used the modified name `Id`.