# Omit object property during json serialization

Tags: c#, javascript, json, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC Controller. Json method in order to send json result object to my javascript function.

From time to time I want to omit one of my object's property from the json result object.

How can I achive it?

This is my .NET object:

```
    public class jsTreeModel
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public JsTreeAttribute Att { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public List<jsTreeModel> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

I this case I want to omit the 'Children' property from the json result.

Any idea?

Comment: Looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372955/best-way-to-filter-domain-objects-for-json-output-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Json.NET as your serializer, you can omit a property fairly simply:

```
public class jsTreeModel
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public JsTreeAttribute Att { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<jsTreeModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I hope this helps you!